# Chef - How to run a cook book on a node

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, knife, cookbook

I have setup a chef server and nodes. Now I want to run my cook book on a specific node. Is there a way to run a custom made cook book on a node using chef-dk without bootstrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Chef requires a local agent program called `chef-client` (or sometimes `chef-solo` but that is only for advanced usage). You can install this agent however you like, `knife bootstrap` is one option but you could bake it into your base OS image if you prefer.

Comment: I have bootstrapped using knife and all the nodes have chef-client installed. Is there any way to run a cookbook in a node from my PC?

Comment: `knife ssh` is the usual tool, though for a single machine it doesn't get you much :)